# Is there any way to point location in Google map as Location written in EditText by user android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I have Edit Text with this property.

```
           <EditText
                android:id="@+id/street_address"
                style="@style/create_event_infotext_normal"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/extra_desc"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" />
```

I have map fragment with this property.

```
     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

I need whatever location written in EditText that must be pointed by Google Map directly.

Comment: What you want to do? clear first

Comment: I want to point location in Google map that is written in EditText by user(here the id of edittext is street_address)

Comment: ok i have a best solution for this. wait for a while

Comment: As I start typing location in EditText(street_address), It also need to show the suggestions of matching locations(addresses). How can I do that????

Comment: use android reverse geo coding library to find coordinate of location the set the map coordinate to show the location

Answer (score 0):

This is what i'm trying to do right now.
I'm using what's google give me : https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

I have an AsyncTask with download the data and parse the content, so the result is the list of places. (method autocomplete)

In my main activity I have an autocompletetextview and a TextWatcher on it. When I wrote something in my autocompletetextview, I user the autocomplete method, and I get the places.

Hope this will help you.